# How can I get a data from one html form and display it on another?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm using only JS and I want to get a username from one html and display it on the another html page. I'm a beginner on the programming and I have two questions:

- Can I use only one JS file to do this? If yes, how?
- Why it isn't working?

First page

```
    <main>
        <form action="">
           <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="login" placeholder="Login">
           <a href="password.html" id='logar'>LOGAR!</a>
        </form>
        <span id='spanlogin'></span>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

```
var login = document.getElementById('login').value;

localStorage.setItem("thelogin", login);
```

Second Page

```
    <main>
        <div>
            <span id='showlogin'></span>
        </div>
        <div class="senha">
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="second.js"></script>
```

```
var ologin = localStorage.getItem('thelogin');

function showthelogin(){
    document.getElementById('showlogin').innerHTML = ologin
}

window.onload = showthelogin()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: traditionally: form submit to server, server responds with new page with submitted data - alternative: use browsers localStorage API - well documented on MDN

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do it in the traditional way?

Comment: you mean submit a form to the server side? by submitting a form to the server side, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, the login button is just a link, it's not running the js on the first page. The js executes immediately on page load when the form is still empty. If you wrap it in a function and call the function on click, it will do what you want.

What you want, might not be what you need, but getting things to do what we want them to do can help us better understand what we need.

main.js

```
function savePassword(){
    var login = document.getElementById('login').value;
    localStorage.setItem("thelogin", login);    
}
```

first page:

```
<a href="password.html" id='logar' onclick="savePassword()">LOGAR!</a>
```

In answer to your first question, you can do it with just one page. For example, read about [Single-page applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA).

Note that the way you're doing it is not the same thing as ['submitting' the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).

Comment: Yeah, I just want to display the username and transfer the user to another page, to enter the password, like a page that I am copying. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

"For documents loaded from file: URLs (that is, files opened in the browser directly from the user’s local filesystem, rather than being served from a web server) the requirements for localStorage behavior are undefined and may vary among different browsers.

In all current browsers, localStorage seems to return a different object for each file: URL. In other words, each file: URL seems to have its own unique local-storage area. But there are no guarantees about that behavior, so you shouldn’t rely on it because, as mentioned above, the requirements for file: URLs remains undefined."

Its from developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Oh, I'm using the Opera GX to test it. Maybe if i change to Chrome it could work. Thanks for the help, I'll try it and get you feedback.

Comment: @HugoFolloni If you use a web server localStorage will be shared. Instead of clicking the file, you will browse to localhost:8000/filename.html, the same as for visiting a normal website, except that it's on your local machine. Here is a [list of ways to start a development test server](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255).

Comment: Yeah, I use the Open with Live Server option of the VSCode, which opens the file on a 5500 port. But it stills not working. :c